# How do I generate a number of text boxes depending on a stored value?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I need to create a number of input boxes depending on a value in a backing bean. If the product allows 5 users I need 5 sets of input fields.

The number of input boxes is known when I load the page.

Any ideas?
This one has had me stumped for a while now.

Comment: Hmmm, editing seems to knock off comments. Sorry...

Comment: I deleted it myself. I checked your question history and confirmed that you were using JSF 2.0 on Facelets and then I posted the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the bean prepare a `List<Item>` based on the number.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private int count;
    private List<Item> items;

    public Bean() {
        count = 5;
        items = new ArrayList<Item>();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            items.add(new Item());
        }
    }

    public void submit() {
        System.out.println(items);
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

}
```

Where the `Item` is just a simple Javabean with a `value` property.

Let the view iterate over it using `<ui:repeat>` or `<h:dataTable>`.

```
<h:form>
    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
        <h:inputText value="#{item.value}" /><br />
    </ui:repeat>

    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot tomorrow. Glassfish just borked, I think it's a sign that I should crash.

Comment: I am using the same approach but the value is always coming as null inside submit(). Why so ?

Comment: @abhinay: Then you're not using exactly the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

It would be difficult to do in plain Jsf. You can write your own component based on a Javascript library and Ajax. (ajax is optional) or if you could use a variant of JSF like IceFaces or Rich Faces then the framework will do most of the heavy lifting for you.

For example in case of Icefaces it can be implemented using  a [simple panel series](http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. I've edited the original but I forgot to mention that I know before hand how many components to load. I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yes that does simplify your problem a bit. I can think of two options on the top of my mind. You could use h:dataTable, it should be the simpler solution. You could also use ui:repeater tag if you are using a  facelets. What you need is a repeater component. The only catch is you should be able to associate correct callback controls.